# javascript for to while statement

Tags: javascript

How would I turn these for statements into a while statement in javascript:

```
    for (left = gridPlace; left <= gridLastPlace; left++){
    for (right = gridOtherPlace; right <= gridLastOtherPlace; right++)
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Magic. Why do you need to? For do the exact same thing as while loops, so you're going to need to nest them just like you did here.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for (x; y; z) { ... }` is the same as `x; while (y) { ... z; }`, so your loops would be:

```
left = gridPlace;
while (left <= gridLastPlace) {
  right = gridOtherPlace;
  while (right <= gridLastOtherPlace) {
    ...
    right++;
  }
  left++;
}
```

Comment: Well, it's the same providing there isn't a `continue` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
var left = gridPlace;

while(left <= gridLastPlace)
{
    var right = gridOtherPlace;

    while(right <= gridLastOtherPlace)
    {

        right++;
    }

    left++;
}
```